# retrieve a primary key data from table

Tags: php, mysql

With php, I am trying to retrieve a primary key so i can insert it into another table as i am trying to connect the two table so I can use them later. I am retrieving a garbage value when print it and when I insert it into usermeet table it insert 0 as id is int so it's inserting a default number,
I have tried everything really but I am at a dead end here.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $names=$_POST['names'];
    $check=$_SESSION['user'];

    $queryselect="SELECT `id` FROM `meeting` WHERE `chairman` = '.$check.'";

    if($resultselect=mysqli_query($db,$queryselect)){
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultselect);
        foreach($names as $user){
            $queryinsert="INSERT INTO `usermeet` (`id`, `username`) VALUES 
                ('".$row['id']."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user)."')";

            if($resultinsert=mysqli_query($db,$queryinsert)){
                 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Meeting have been created')</script>";

                 header('Location: home.php');
             }
             else{
                echo "bad";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want result ? please properly explain.

Comment: Before getting "frustrated", did you read the documentation? First check the documentation : [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @khetesh i want the result so i can link between a two tables one meeting table which has all meeting info and the other table usermeet has all user that participate in the meeting. i want to take the id of the meeting the user which has created the meeting so he then invite the users in the meeting. i hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

> i am retreiving a garbage value when print it

How do you actually print it? With echo or var_dump/print_r. Also did you checked your SELECT-Query, for example in phpMyAdmin? And I might be wrong, but the query doesn't look right:

```
$queryselect="SELECT id FROM meeting WHERE chairman = '".$check."'";
```

You haven't to enclose column names with quotes. Also you combined the variable and the string not correctly.

Just a tip for debugging: Check every step in your code and its returned values. And use var_dump/print_r for it, not echo. Be aware of all values you have in your code and check if they are exactly what you want them to be.

Comment: first of all thank you for the tips and yes i have been using print_r and it doesn't display anything but with echo it display garbage value,and actually i am using a prepared queries from phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

First please check your `id` is set to auto increment then

---

### Try by Removing " Quotations "

```
$queryinsert="INSERT INTO `usermeet` (`id`, `username`) 
VALUES ('.$row['id'].','.mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $user).')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't to enclose column names with quotes. Also you combined the variable and the string not correctly.

```
$queryselect="SELECT id FROM meeting WHERE chairman = '".$check."'";
```

As per you have written a code you have to used mysqli_fetch_array with MYSQLI_ASSOC constant.

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: MYSQLI_ASSOC answered my question what is weird is i have never used it and my professor never used it. and i have written similar code like this in other page and runs like charm with out it. thank you very much